# Scala Package Issue With ZKStringSerializer

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, package

I am trying to use the class ZKStringSerializer, which I get with

```
import kafka.utils.ZKStringSerializer
```

According to the entirety of the internet, and even my own code before I restarted by computer, this should allow my code to work. However, I now get an incredibly confusing compile error,

```
object ZKStringSerializer in package utils cannot be accessed in package kafka.utils
```

This is confusing because this file is not supposed to be in any package, and I don't specify a package anywhere. This is my code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSource.Timestamp
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient
import org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkConnection
import java.util.Properties

import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin
import kafka.admin.{AdminUtils, RackAwareMode}
import kafka.utils.ZKStringSerializer
import kafka.utils.ZkUtils
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.{KafkaProducer, ProducerRecord}


object SpeedTester {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[4]").appName("SpeedTester").config("spark.driver.memory", "8g").getOrCreate()
    val rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger()
    rootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    import spark.implicits._
    val zookeeperConnect = "localhost:2181"
    val sessionTimeoutMs = 10000
    val connectionTimeoutMs = 10000
    val zkClient = new ZkClient(zookeeperConnect, sessionTimeoutMs, connectionTimeoutMs, ZKStringSerializer)
    val topicName = "testTopic"
    val numPartitions = 8
    val replicationFactor = 1
    val topicConfig = new Properties
    val isSecureKafkaCluster = false
    val zkUtils = new ZkUtils(zkClient, new ZkConnection(zookeeperConnect), isSecureKafkaCluster)
    AdminUtils.createTopic(zkUtils, topicName, numPartitions, replicationFactor, topicConfig)

    // Create producer for topic testTopic and actually push values to the topic
    val props = new Properties()
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9592")
    props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)
    val TOPIC = "testTopic"
    for (i <- 1 to 50) {
      val record = new ProducerRecord(TOPIC, "key", s"hello $i")
      producer.send(record)
    }

    val record = new ProducerRecord(TOPIC, "key", "the end" + new java.util.Date)
    producer.send(record)
    producer.flush()
    producer.close()
  }
}
```

Comment: What version of Kafka are you including?

Comment: @cricket_007 0.11.0.0

Comment: `kafka.utils` doesn't exist in the Javadoc http://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/

Answer (score 1):

I know this is too late, but for others who will be looking for the same issue-

In the latest version of kafka,  kafka.utils got deprecated. So please use kafka admin client apis